# Heatmap - How to add server-side code from within the browser

Tags: javascript, browser, monitoring, network-monitoring

We use a heatmap at work (it is secure so I can't post it here and I certainly cannot give the url). Now the heatmap is a sigle image, but it is clickable on different segments - There are different icons on the map and each of them pops up a different window(So it is not just a single click event for the whole image)...

Now this map is generated by a program called Whatsup Gold, and it is definitely not Flash...

The map constantly monitors line connection activity - When an internet line goes down, the 
green icon turns red. The map is refreshed every few minutes...

What I want to know: Is there a way, either using a browser plugin, or Javascript, or any other method to notify me that the status of the map has changed(any change on the map) without having to open the browser window everytime?

Here is the part of the markup of the map...(the whole map)

```
<a href="mappickhost.asp?map=WhatsUpTL.wup">
   <img border="0" src="WUG1.jpg" ismap="">
</a>
```

Update:

Request and Response headers(As retrieved from Firebugs Network tab)

**Request:**

```
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate

Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5

Authorization:  Basic dGxpbms6dGxpbms=

Cache-Control:  max-age=0

Connection: keep-alive

Host:           ***************
```

**Response**

```
Cache-Control   no-cache

Content-Type    image/jpeg

Date    Fri, 17 May 2013 07:06:30 GMT

Expires Mon, 17 Jul 1980 20:00:00 GMT

Pragma  no-cache

Server  WhatsUp_Gold/8.0
```

Comment: You could check the console in Chrome or FireFox to see what it connects to (my guess is xhr request). Inspect the response (my guess it's JSON or xml). Then write a deskop/console app in any language you want to connect to that service. There maybe a problem if it needs authentication and session cookies that make writing it very difficult.

Comment: thanks for the reply.."see what it connects to"...How would I see that? All I can see is the link the map connect to, and it is posted in my code above...

Comment: I've added an answer with a screenshot of Firebug, it's realy handy to check out what JavaScript is doing or to change styles and manipulate html elements. If you haven't used it yet than I'll advice you to get familiar with it because you will save a lot of time trying to figure out how things work or why they stopped working.

Comment: I see you've updated your question. Is that the initial loading of the page and it's images or a repeated connection to somewhere after the page and all it's images have loaded? I can see that the page or service has basic authentication so whatever application you're going to write for it has to implement that as well by setting request headers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a screenshot of firebug console in firefox (press F12 to open it). I executed a xmlhttprequest (line at the bottom) and you can see (the black line) that it connected to stackoverflow. Firebug shows xhr connections in the console by default but you can select what you want to see by clicking the little arrow button to the right of the word "Console" in the tab that activates the console.

Even having the console open with StackOverflow shows that the site connects every so often to update question status and comments.

If nothing shows up there than it might show in the Net tab. It has to make a connection to somewhere to see if network is still up. If it connects to a service than xhr is likely if it just tries to download a textfile sometmes or sets the src of an image than it'll show up only in the net tab every time it checks.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. So what you are saying is that there should be a new image that is posted everytime the heatmap changes? since the all the content on the map is contained in an image...So we can basically set up an event listener for the image, to see when the image changes? But if the image is overwritten as the same filename how would you know it is a new image?

Comment: No, you are completely missing the point. The image probably is set or decorated by javascript and the javascript connects to a service that will list availability of the network. Have you checked the console and do you see the page making requests after the page finished loading?

Comment: Oh I see. No I am not so familiar with the advanced features of the console. Maybe I should start learning it...I will look and come back to you

Comment: @DextrousDave Did you have any luck figuring it out? My guess is that it's using xmlhttprequest to some server that will report and then JS will update the image. If that's the case you could see the requests in the firebug console. Should be the same when you open stackoverflow, press F12 and wait for a couple of minutes. SO connects every so often with xmlhttprequests as well.

Comment: cool man. found it. Every minute, as set by the "http-equiv="REFRESH"" meta tag, there is a request. How do I look at what type of request it is? I found the following under the 'Accept' label under the Headers tab in Firebug -  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Comment: I think if you click around the request you'll be able to see the response, it might be empty if nothing changed but my guess is that it's JSON. So you know the URL, can check what data is sent in the request and check out the response. From here you could try to reverse engineer how to do this in (for example) PHP curl. It would not be easy though because you need to authenticate as well I think. If there is no documentation on the service than you'll have to guess a lot.

Answer (score 0):

> We use a heatmap at work (it is secure so I can't post it here and I certainly cannot give the url). Now the heatmap is a sigle image, but it is clickable on different segments

Surely it's *not just the image that's causing interaction*. Plain images can't do that. If it's not Flash, then it could be JavaScript powering it. There must be some library and *it could have an API*. I suggest you start reading the documentation (if any).

> The map constantly monitors line connection activity

This is done in a lot of ways, and the most common is polling AJAX or Web Sockets. To check this out, you can take a look at the Network Tab of the browser's debugger. If there's a supported API, you can check it out first and save the hassle of debugging the implementation.

If no API exists, inspect the requests and find a way to replicate it. Once you can replicate it or use the API, you can create your plugin or create a custom app for it.

Comment: Yup documentation miht be a good idea...will see if I can find some. Network tab? What network tab are you referring to?

Comment: @DextrousDave of the browser's debugger.

Comment: See my update on the question. Also, the heatmap is displayed as a single image, so I guess that whenever something on the map changes, the image is regenerated and a new image is inserted into the DOM. Or is my assumption wrong here?

Comment: @DextrousDave You could be right. It could be that the map image is periodically generated by the server, and periodically refreshed by the browser. Interaction is done by JS. If only we see a demo can we actually suggest a more proper solution.

Comment: yes I understand, but I even if I did post the link/demo here, you will not be able to access it - very secure- Heavily firewalled against any PC out of the company network